# callback of the callback function node js

Tags: javascript

So in Node we use async functions. And to do that we use callback functions as parameters. But how do I execute the final function after which I want to terminate the code? Just pass the empty function? Here's example:

```
fs.mkdir('stuff', function(){
    fs.readFile('readMe.txt', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
        fs.writeFile('./stuff/writeMe.txt', data);
    });
});
```

mkdir has callback function - all fine

readFile has callback function - all fine

writeFile has NOT callback function because that's the last thing I want to do, but then I get an error in console: 
"DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated."

Should I every time I do that, pass an empty function as a callback to avoid the error? What's the best practice for this?

Comment: Your callbacks do not handle any error condition....

Answer (score 3):

> Should I every time I do that, pass an empty function as a callback to avoid the error?

No.

> What's the best practice for this?

Pass in a function and handle any errors it reports. You also need to handle errors from `mkdir` and `readFile`, which currently you're ignoring.

E.g.:

```
fs.mkdir('stuff', function(err) {
    if (err) {
        // Do something with the fact mkdir failed
    } else {
        fs.readFile('readMe.txt', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                // Do something with the fact readFile failed
            } else {
                fs.writeFile('./stuff/writeMe.txt', data, function(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        // Do something with the fact writeFile failed
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

...which is a fair example of callback hell, which is part of the motivation of using promises instead. You could promisify the fs API (using any of several libs, such as [`promisify`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promisify)) and do it like this:

```
fsp.mkdir('stuff')
.then(() => fsp.readFile('readMe.txt', 'utf8'))
.then(data => fsp.writeFile('./stuff/writeMe.txt', data))
.catch(err => {
    // Do something with the fact something failed
});
```

...where `fsp` is a placeholder for the promisified fs API.

In Node 8.x+, you could use `async`/`await` to write synchronous-looking code with those promisified APIs:

```
// This must be inside an `async` function
try {
    fsp.mkdir('stuff');
    const data = await fsp.readFile('readMe.txt', 'utf8');
    await fsp.writeFile('./stuff/writeMe.txt', data);
} catch (err) {
    // Do something with the fact something failed
}
```

Comment: Seconded. Always handle errors properly for best practice. Never know what can go wrong.

Comment: Thx for the response, I'll read a bit so I understand your answer and then I'll accept it.

Comment: could we create fuction to to try catch to write or read file ? and then call that function, to reuseable?

Comment: @ZumDummi - Of course, you can always encapsulate logic in a reusable function. Note that the function would be asynchronous.

Comment: can u give me example to callback with try catch ??

Comment: @ZumDummi - I'm afraid I don't quite understand what you're asking.

Comment: can you give me example how to create function callback  to readFile ? with try catch inside that function

Answer (score 0):

You can use writeFileSync instead.

```
fs.mkdir('stuff', function(){
    fs.readFile('readMe.txt', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
        fs.writeFileSync('./stuff/writeMe.txt', data);
    });
});
```

Comment: Just not in a server application that needs to be responsive. A console script, though, sure. But in a console script you could use the `Sync` version of all three.

Comment: I thought the point of Node is to not use blocking Sync versions at all in the server application?

Comment: True. I was just providing a direct solution to what OP was asking for, which was a `writeFile` without a callback.

Comment: @user3784950: That depends. If you're writing a server, absolutely, avoid sync I/O like the plague. If you're writing a utility whose only job is the I/O operations that doesn't need to do anything else at all while it's doing them, sync I/O is fine. Of course, later if you need to do the same thing in a different context where responsiveness matters, you won't be able to reuse sync code. And with `async`/`await`, the benefits of async I/O can be realized while still writing nice simple, sync-looking code.